# Transform string into Python Dictionary with recursion and regex

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I need to transform a string into a dictionary. To be more specific I am needing to parse Auditd messages into dictionaries. EX:
string:

```
msg=audit(123.123:123): pid=2514 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=3 subj=random_ex:random_ex:random_ex:d3-d3:w0.c12    30 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_localuser acct="lemoney" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? a    ddr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
```

here are some alternates:

```
msg=audit(1234902.147:88): pid=254 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=3 subj=random_ex:random_ex:random_ex:d3-d3:w0.c12    30 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_localuser acct="lemoney" exe="/usr/bin/grep" hostname=? a    ddr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'

msg=audit(432787023.324:77): pid=1254 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=3 subj=random_ex:random_ex:random_ex:d3-d3:w0.c12    30 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_localuser acct="lemoney" exe="/usr/bin/tail" hostname=? a    ddr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
```

what I would like is:

```
{
  msg: 'audit(...',
  pid: ...,
  uid: ...,
  mess: {
    op: PAM...,
    grantors=pam_unix...
  }
}
```

I am really hitting my head on this I know I need a regex and it needs to be recursive but I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: yes. Each one is an individual entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go (with the help of some regular expressions):

```
import re

string = """
msg=audit(1234902.147:88): pid=254 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=3 subj=random_ex:random_ex:random_ex:d3-d3:w0.c12    30 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_localuser acct="lemoney" exe="/usr/bin/grep" hostname=? a    ddr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'

msg=audit(432787023.324:77): pid=1254 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=3 subj=random_ex:random_ex:random_ex:d3-d3:w0.c12    30 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_localuser acct="lemoney" exe="/usr/bin/tail" hostname=? a    ddr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
"""

# lines regex
entries = re.compile(r'^msg=.+', re.MULTILINE)

# outer regex
rx = re.compile("""
    ((\w+)='([^']+)') # longer group
    |             # or
    (\w+=\S+)     # single items
    """, re.VERBOSE)

# inner regex
ry = re.compile("(\w+)=(\S+)")

for entry in entries.finditer(string):
  result = dict()
  for match in rx.finditer(entry.group(0)):
    try:
      key, value = match.group(4).split('=')
      result[key] = value
    except:
      #key = match.group(2)

      inner = dict()
      for m in ry.finditer(match.group(3)):
        inner[m.group(1)] = m.group(2)

      result["mess"] = inner

  print(result)
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/MsqMst).

Comment: Nice. Thank you so much sir. I was dealing in for loops before

Comment: The first msg value (the one with 123.123:123) is overwritten. I am refactoring but any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility, but no regular expressions were killed in the process of making this:

```
import shlex
from collections import OrderedDict

def split_on_equals_to_dict(string_to_split):
    split_dict = OrderedDict()
    for i, item in enumerate(shlex.split(string_to_split)):
        number_of_equals = item.count('=')
        if number_of_equals == 0:
            split_dict[item] = None
        elif number_of_equals == 1:
            split_dict.update(dict([item.split('=')]))
        else:
            tag, value = tuple(item.split('=', 1))
            split_dict[tag] = split_on_equals_to_dict(value)
    return split_dict

log_str="""audit(123.123:123): pid=2514 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=3 subj=random_ex:random_ex:random_ex:d3-d3:w0.c12    30 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_localuser acct="lemoney" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? a    ddr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'"""
log_dict = split_on_equals_to_dict(log_str)
```

There is some ambiguity in the string provided.  I dealt with this by using an OrderedDict.